# Material UI icon not working with firefox in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am using `TextField` to select the time. But when I'm choosing the time, the timepicker works fine with the Chrome browser but `down icon` changes to `cross icon` in Firefox.

Here is the screenshot what I need in FireFox. But in chrome it is working perfectly fine. I only need in firefox:

[image]

Here is what I'm getting in firefox:

[image]

Here is the code I've done so far:

```
<TextField
  id="time"
  type="time"
  style={{
    width: "148px",
    marginLeft: 6,
    marginRight: 6,
    padding: "2px 0px 3px 6px",
  }}
  defaultValue="03:30"
  value={timeChange}
  onChange={handleTimeChange}
  className={classes.textField}
  color="secondary"
  InputProps={{
    disableUnderline: true,
    classes: {
      input: classes.floatingLabelFocusStyle,
    },
  }}
/>;
```

And CSS is here:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  select: {
    color: "black",
  },
  icon: { color: "#c4c4c4" },
  textField: {
    font: "normal normal normal 14px Open Sans",
    background: "#FFFFFF 0% 0 % no - repeat padding- box",
    border: "1px solid #C4C4C4",
    borderRadius: "2px",
    color: "#f5f5f5",
  },
  floatingLabelFocusStyle: {
    font: "normal normal normal 14px Open Sans",
  },
  input: {
    color: "white",
  },
}));
```

And SCSS:

```
input[type="time"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
                 
                    margin-right: 7px;
                    cursor: pointer;
                    background:url(https://www.materialui.co/materialIcons/hardware/keyboard_arrow_down_grey_27x27.png);
                }
```

Any fix for this?. Thank you.

Comment: could you pls share your code snippet on glitch.com or codepen or a similar site; we can look into it and provide a solution

Comment: Here is the link: 
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/darkened-quirky-dill. I have added all the codes in the src/pages folder

Comment: tried but no luck; it's better to go with custom time controls. URL has some control list pls check - https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-date-time-picker.html